# How To Play Remote Video(mp4) file with AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I have been working for a long time to play .mp4 file which is located Remote location using AVPlayer. The Player is playing the audio track of the mp4 file but not the video.

i am using the following code to play the mp4 file.

```
_remoteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zfete.com/usermedia/2/2d97bd26-8b60-11e2-94ea-000c29072353.mp4"];
 self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:_remoteURL];
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];

[(AVPlayerView *)self.view setPlayer:_player];

_player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];

[_player play];
```

Please let me know where exactly i am going wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple has an example project showing you how to use `AVPlayer` here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011060

Comment: You are using a (badly named!) third-party class of some sort, AVPlayerView. So there is a lot of very important code going on behind the scenes that you are not showing us, which could be doing something wrong. On the other hand, playing video with an AVPlayer and an AVPlayerLayer is very easy, so why not just do that, and avoid dependence on this third-party code?

Comment: Hi matt that is not a third party call. That is simply type casting the view object with AVPlayerView. as you said i am using AVPlayer.

Comment: That is not third party it is: AVKit/AVPlayerView.h